# $.post works but not $.get ? On a different domain?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am stuck on an issue with reading data from a server.  The data is stored as a csv string and i am using php to read the data.

## Reading Data

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/plain'); 
    $csv = file_get_contents('string.csv'); 
    echo $csv; 
?>

$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://www.foobar.com/csv.php',
    async: false,
    data: null, 
    success: function(text) { 
        sv_serverArray = text.split(",");
        alert(sv_serverArray);
    } 
});
```

The Ajax call is done on the domain http://www.example.com the php file is served on http://foobar.com/csv.php

When i post the data from http://www.example.com to http://www.foobar.com/write.php it works!  But not the other way around.

## Writing Data

```
<?php
    $list = $_POST["array"];
    $fp = fopen('string.csv', 'w');
    fputcsv($fp, $list);
    fclose($fp);
?>

$.post("http://www.foobar.com/write.php", { 'array': sv_defaultArray});
```

What is the issue and why can i only write and not read ?! if anything i should be getting errors the other way around !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$.post()` generates a  underwater, and uses that to post. When posted it is a real request.
The `$.get()` uses a XMLHttpRequest, which is bound by the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The best way to circumvent this is [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP). (either convert the CSV to json, or encapsulate it).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do [Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) in this way for security purposes

Read this: [Cross domain AJAX querying with jQuery](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check the cross domain solutions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_Domain_Solutions)..